# Error after migrating Django project from MySQL to PostgreSQL

Tags: django, postgresql

I am migrating a Django project from MySQL to PostGreSQL.

I have been able to successfully transfer database from MySQL to PostGreSQL. But running the site gives me the following error:

```
Unhandled exception in thread started by <function wrapper at 0x7f68d9b266e0>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/root/.virtualenvs/thakurani/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/utils/autoreload.py", line 228, in wrapper
    _exception = sys.exc_info()
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'exc_info'
```

Is this error coming, because of some packages not being installed. I have installed psycopg2, python-dev, libpq-dev.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I resolved the error myself.
I was using:

```
python manage.py runserver 8000
```

whereas we have to specify the IP Address too i.e.:

```
python manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000
```